# shared pointer assertion fail after iteration in a loop

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, iterator, shared-ptr

I am new to shared_ptr from boost and am considering to iterate over my set to get the best object. 
**EDIT: added information about first_world**

```
std::set<World::CPtr> first_world = ... // long call, but it gets a set of constant shared pointers to the class World, where various methods exist

   typedef boost::shared_ptr<World const> CPtr;
   World::CPtr best = *(first_world.begin());
   for (World::CPtr lo : first_world) {
     if (best->getValue() >= lo->getValue() ){
       best = lo;
     }
   }
```

Later I want to use that shared pointer, My program crashes with communicate that Assertion `px != 0' failed. I followed the rules from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices), I mean I used a shared pointer as iterator in a loop but then I assign it to another pointer. Is that bad practice, is there better practice?

```
cout << "name is: " << best->getDefinition() << endl;
```

Comment: Why are you using `boost::shared_ptr` when you're obviously using C++11?

Comment: @molbdnilo Why not? Seems rather irrelevant. Last time I checked the types are not the same, and it makes sense to use the type that your code base requires...

Comment: well c++11 is not necessary, I would change it to older standard - what I want to understand is why that does not work, how to make it work.

Comment: Could you share the declaration of `first_world`? What kind of container is it, and what's the element type?

Comment: @MarkWaterman updated. Sorry for omitting such obviously needed information.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's blatantly wrong in what's pasted there, so there's probably going to be a mistake in the long call that creates the set.

For example, it would be easy to mess this up if raw pointers are involved when adding elements to the set. Consider this situation, a concrete illustration of a common mistake that's sort of alluded to in your Best Practices link:

```
std::set<World::CPtr> first_world;

World* pWorld = new World();

// Bad:
first_world.insert(World::CPtr(pWorld));
first_world.insert(World::CPtr(pWorld));

// Oops!! You now have two independently refcounted entries in first_world!

// emplace is just as deadly, but more subtle.
// Now you'll have three shared pointers in your set:
first_world.emplace(pWorld);
```

If you look through your entries in `first_world` and see duplicates then you'll know you're in trouble. To avoid mistakes like this, make sure you only construct shared_ptrs from other shared_ptrs (or `boost::make_shared`).

So that's tip #1: *Avoid constructing `shared_ptrs` from a raw pointers*. (That includes the `this` pointer if Worlds are adding themselves to your set... if you're doing that, better start googling `enable_shared_from_this`).

Now let's follow that guideline to get expected behavior:

```
std::set<World::CPtr> first_world;

World::CPtr spWorld1 = boost::make_shared<World>();
World::CPtr spWorld2{spWorld1};

first_world.insert(spWorld1);
first_world.insert(spWorld2);
// Just one element in first_world now, as expected.
```

Finally, a few (somewhat unrelated) suggestions:

- `std::set` as you've declared it is only looking at the *address* of World objects on the heap when it compares entries. So if you have two different Worlds on the heap that are logically identical then they'll both have distinct entries in the set. Is that your intent? You'll need to plug in your own custom compare function (std::set's second template argument) to do a deep comparison of Worlds if you want to avoid logical duplicates.
- Check to make sure that `first_world` isn't empty before looking for the max, otherwise bad things will happen.
- Standard algorithms are your friend! Consider using the [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm instead of a raw loop. (This makes it easier for other people to reason about what you're doing with a quick glance).