# error: ‘boost::array’ is not a type

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, boost

I have created a simple class as follows. What I am attempting to do here is to convert boost::array to a string so that it can be printed out or used for some other purpose.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <exception>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


class buffer_manager
{
  public:
    buffer_manager()
    {   

    }   
    ~buffer_manager()
    {   

    }   
    std::string message_buffer(boost::array buf)
    {   
        message = boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), recv_buf.end(), back_inserter(result));
        return message;
    }   

private:
  boost::array<unsigned char, 4096> recv_buf = {{0}};
  std::string message;
};
```

While compiling I seem to get a strange error.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -pedantic -c buffer_manager.cpp -o buffer_manager.o
buffer_manager.cpp:26:39: error: ‘boost::array’ is not a type
     std::string message_buffer(boost::array buf)
                                       ^
buffer_manager.cpp: In member function ‘std::string buffer_manager::message_buffer(int)’:
buffer_manager.cpp:28:89: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
         message = boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), recv_buf.end(), back_inserter(result));
                                                                                         ^
buffer_manager.cpp:28:95: error: ‘back_inserter’ was not declared in this scope
         message = boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), recv_buf.end(), back_inserter(result));
                                                                                               ^
buffer_manager.cpp:28:95: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from buffer_manager.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:480:5: note:   ‘std::back_inserter’
     back_inserter(_Container& __x)
     ^
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'buffer_manager.o' failed
```

Comment: If you're using C++11, why not use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: `boost::array` is templated, you haven't specified which template to use.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can we stop [saying silly unrelated things like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278937/shared-pointer-assertion-fail-after-iteration-in-a-loop#comment58270095_35278937)? It's *very* obvious that this has nothing to do with op's question in any way, shape or form. The types are **not** the same anyways.

Comment: @sehe using the best tool for the job is a part of problem solving. IMO it is good to mention such things in case OP was unaware of them

Comment: @M.M so, when you see 7 boost headers being included, you think it's worthwhile to explain that some things can be done differently? Mmm. I'm not convinced in this case

Comment: @sehe: Isn't questioning the question one of the valid use cases for *comments*? An answer which does nothing but suggest `std::array` is bad, but comments are not answers.

Comment: @ChristianHackl But if _this_ is "questioning the question" then what the hell did he think the question was? Suggesting `std::array` is more than useless here. It's really more like "kneejerking the question" then :)

Comment: @sehe: I really don't see what's so bad about it. In comments, you talk about the question, rather than answering it. It seems only logical to talk about `std::array` when seeing `boost::array`.

Comment: If you like knee-jerking a lot, maybe. I suppose it makes a lot of sense then. (Can I take this moment to tell you about my lord and saviour...?)

Comment: Oh and I forget to mention why it is bad: it distracts and confuses. Often (not in this particular case) it can be read as a reprimand ("just use X instead of Y" or "why are you (even) using Z") and leads to a higher risk of downvotes for a fine question.

Comment: @sehe: I think nobody here, including the OP, had any problem with Joachim's comment until you stepped in. Of course, downvoting a question only because it uses the wrong tool would be silly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104122/discussion-between-sehe-and-christian-hackl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since boost::array is a template type, you need to have a template parameter when you use the boost::array as a parameter to a function. I recommend using a typedef:

```
typedef boost::array<unsigned char, 4096> My_Array_Type;

//...
std::string message_buffer(My_Array_Type& buf);
//...
My_Array_Type rec_buf;
```

**Edit 1:**
In your situation, you may find the `std::vector` a better choice.  Also, a `typedef` will be convenient here also.

Comment: There are two more errors: `std::back_inserter` used unqualified and `result` not declared in the function body.

Comment: ...or template the member function itself to gather the requisite template parameters, i.e. `template<class T, std::size_t N> std::string message_buffer(boost::array<T,N> const& buf) {...}`. Though, like most situations of this kind, an iterator pair would be considerably more flexible.